# Title: Generation of designer file failed: Unknown server tag 'cc1:Rating

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to convert a website to a web application project.
while doing that i got some error say:
"Generation of designer file failed: Unknown server tag 'cc1:Rating'"
In my few pages i am using Ajaxcontrol toolkit, so i have registered the tag in the page.
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
when i try to convert this page, its giving me the error. So what could be the work around to fix this issue????

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

Configure your tag prefix in web.config if you have many pages that are using the toolkit. It's fine even if you keep it in the page itself.

Make sure you have a reference to the AjaxControlToolkit in your application and change the assembly name to that of the web application that contains the controls just during the conversion:

```
<add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="WebApplicationHavingTheControlsASsemblyName"/>
```